# Cannot open a file to read login data from in C

Tags: c, debugging, read-write

This function is for a login system in C. It launches correctly and is seemingly proper code according to language syntax. When I try to open the file after entering username/password, it returns the "Error, try again" message. The file is a .txt file with two lines, the username and password.

```
void login()
{
   while (1)
   {
       printf("---- Bank Management ----\n\n");
       printf("Please login...\n");
       
       char username[25] = {'\0'};
       printf("\nEnter username:\n");
       fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
       
       int c = 0;
       while (c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF);
           
       char password[25] = {'\0'};
       printf("\nEnter password:\n");
       fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
           
       char extension[5] = ".txt";
       char fileName[31] = {'\0'};
       strcpy(fileName, username);
       strcat(fileName, extension);
       
       FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           
       if (fp != NULL)
       {
           char setUsername[5] = "bank";
           char setPassword[5] = "temp";
           char fileContents1[25] = {'\0'};
           char fileContents2[25] = {'\0'};
               
           for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
           {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    fgets(fileContents1, sizeof(fileContents1), fp);
                        
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        fgets(fileContents2, sizeof(fileContents2), fp);
                    }
                }
                  
                if ((strcmp(setUsername, fileContents1) != 0) && (strcmp(setPassword, fileContents2) != 0))
                {
                    menu();
                } else
                {
                    printf("\nInvalid username or password, try again.\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            printf("\nError, try again.\n\n");
            continue;
        }
           
        fclose(fp); 
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the `while (c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF);` for before the second entry? You've already read the newline with the previous `fgets()`? It's wrongly parenthesized anyway: `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Comment: If `fopen` returns NULL, you should include the reason for the error in the error message.  Also, write your error messages to stderr:  `fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s: %s\n", fileName, strerror(errno));`.  Or just use `perror(fileName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping all your code in `if( fp != NULL )`, check for the error and bail out immediately.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if( fp == NULL ) {
  perror(fileName);
}

// Without a size, C will figure it out.
char setUsername[] = "bank";
char setPassword[] = "temp";
...
```

Use [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) to a decent error message with a reason.

```
myusername
.txt: No such file or directory.
```

Whoops, the username has a newline.

---

`fgets` reads the whole line, including the newline. That newline has to be stripped off.

That might be what `while (c = getchar() != '\n' && c != EOF);` is trying to do, but it isn't. It's reading input until it sees a newline or end-of-file... and throwing the input out. That's why the user has to hit enter twice after entering their username.

`fgets` has already read the username from input into memory. We can write a little function to jump to the last character of the string and turn the newline into a null.

```
void strip_newline(char *string) {
    char *end = string + strlen(string) - 1;
    if( *end == '\n' ) {
        *end = '\0';
    }
}
```

Or we can use `scanf` because it strips trailing whitespace.

```
// "" is equivalent to {'\0'} and easier to understand.
char username[25] = "";
printf("\nEnter username:\n");
// Unlike fgets, scanf does not leave space for the null byte.
scanf("%24s", username);

char password[25] = "";
printf("\nEnter password:\n");
scanf("%24s", password);
```

Normally [`scanf` is to be avoided](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), but its fine for this simple parsing.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
fgets(...) statements.
```

when reading input,  the '\n' is included in the data read.

So must remove that char.